# dns_probe_finished_nxdomain on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

Last weekend, I transferred my domain from LWS to AWS Route 53.

I did change the NS server, the DNSSEC, DS record, etc... and everything looks like it's working.

I can access my website (garetabecane.fr) from my phone, from my personal wifi but at work, everyone who is connected to the wifi can't access it and get this error : "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

I'm not sure if it's because of a bad configuration or because the propagation takes time, or because the wifi is caching the previous DNS (??)

I'm using an Amazon Lightsail server with LAMP, and I configured the DNS on Amazon Route 53.

I tried looking for this error but every solution I found was about resetting my DNS client on my computer.

In my case, I'm not the only one facing this issue with my website.

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but 1) "because the propagation takes time": DNS has no propagation and specifically when you troubleshoot it you should query authoritative nameservers first to have correct replies and 2) as you can see on https://dnsviz.net/d/garetabecane.fr/Y3OZxA/dnssec/ - a free online troubleshooting tool you should always use - you have a SEVERE DNSSEC misconfiguration. You can't just transfer a DNSSEC enabled domain between DNS providers and hope that will work. It won't. Ask your DNS provider for guidance now to fix this.

Comment: You should probably first go back to a simple situation without DNSSEC as obviously it is not something you are clear on right now, so go to your registrar - Gandi - and make it remove the DS record at registry. It has a 12 hours TTL, so once you did the operation, wait for that delay and then retest your domain.